# Compare two tables without primary keys

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison

I have two tables that do not have primary keys. Both tables have the same number of columns and they look like this:

```
|    Table_1    |     |    Table_2    |
+---+---+---+---+     +---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D |     | A | B | C | D |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |     | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |     | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
+---+---+---+---+     +---+---+---+---+
```

I want to compare column "A" from Table_1 with column "A" from Table_2 and display the differences.
This is the query that Im currently using:

```
SELECT t1.A, t1.B, t1.C, t1.D
FROM Table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2
ON t1.A = t2.A
WHERE t2.A IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.A, t2.B, t2.C, t2.D
FROM Table_2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table_1 t1
ON t2.A = t1.A
WHERE t1.A IS NULL
```

This is the result that Im getting from the query:

```
|     Result    |
+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

My desired result is this:

```
|                Result                 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|t1.A|t2.A|t1.B|t2.B|t1.C|t2.C|t1.D|t2.D|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: You're only selecting 4 columns in your queries, how do you expect to get 8 columns in the result?

Comment: If you want to join them into a single row, what's the joining condition?

Comment: In your example it's simple -- there's just one different row in each table, and you concatenate them. But what about the more general case where there are multiple differences? How would they be combined to get the kind of result you want.

Comment: There are two tables with no primary keys. In both tables column A is expected to have the same values. Columns B, C and D could have non matching or matching values. The requirements are to get only the non matching values from column A and display them together in one row. Something like, column A from Table_1 is expected result and column A from Table_2 is actual result. The query that Im using above displays the differences from the tables in but in two rows, the aim is to have them on one row, like in the desired result above.

Comment: What if all the rows don't match? How do you know which ones to pair up in the same row of the results?

Comment: And what if there are different numbers of non-matching rows in the two tables?

Answer (score 0):

I interpret this as wanting the B/C/D values that are the same with different `A` values.  You can use `JOIN`:

```
select *
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.B = t2.B and t1.C = t2.C and t1.D = t2.D
where t1.A <> t2.A;
```

This is at least consistent with your result set.

EDIT:

If you just want two columns where the rows are different, then I would suggest:

```
select max(a1) as a1, max(b1) as b1, max(c1) as c1, max(d1) as d1,
       max(a2) as a2, max(b2) as b2, max(c2) as c2, max(d2) as d2
from ((select a as a1, b as b1, c as c1, d as d1,
              null as a2, null as b2, null as c2, null as d2, 
              row_number() over (order by a) as seqnum
       from table1 t1
       where not exists (select 1
                         from table2 t2
                         where t2.a = t1.a and t2.b = t1.b and t1.c = t2.c and t1.d = t2.d
                        )
      ) union all
      (select null as a1, null as b1, null as c1, null as d1, 
              a, b, c, d,
              row_number() over (order by a) as seqnum
       from table1 t2
       where not exists (select 1
                         from table1 t1
                         where t2.a = t1.a and t2.b = t1.b and t1.c = t2.c and t1.d = t2.d
                        )
      )
     ) t12
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: The requirements are to get the non matching values from table_1 and table_2 in column "A" and display them in one row next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL 8.0 or later you can use ROW_NUMBER() window like:

```
select 
    t1.A `t1.A`,
    t1.B `t1.B`,
    t1.C `t1.C`,
    t1.D `t1.D`,
    t2.A `t2.A`,
    t2.B `t2.B`,
    t2.C `t2.C`,
    t2.D `t2.D`
from (
  select 
      *,
      row_number() over() rn
  from Table1
) t1
join (
  select 
      *,
      row_number() over() rn
  from Table2
) t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

**Result**

```
+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+
| t1.A | t1.B | t1.C | t1.D | t2.A | t2.B | t2.C | t2.D |
+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+======+
| 1    | 1    | 1    | 1    | 2    | 1    | 1    | 1    |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 2    | 2    | 2    | 2    | 2    | 2    | 2    | 2    |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

[Test SQL code here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=257488c5ba956e4906a72d57a63ad159&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: I would add `ORDER BY` inside the `OVER` clause. Otherwise the query will generate a somewhat random output.

Comment: I think about order but have not idea about field that can be used for order